# Setting the model for a table cell in obj c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift

In Swift, I like to set up my table cell by declaring a model, and once that model is set then I go ahead and update the UI for that particular cell...

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
     var myModel: Model? {
         didSet {
            updateCell()
         }
     }

     func updateCell() {           
        NameLabel.text = myModel.Name
        Img.image = ....
        anotherLabel.text = myModel.anotherLabel
       //and so on
     }
}
```

My table view controller looks more or less like the following

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.myModel = someCollection[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this sort of functionality in objective c? I like this because I can keep my controller light. In Objective C I typically would do something along the lines of....

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];

    cell.NameLabel.text = whatever;
    cell.Img.image = ...
    cell.anotherLabel.text = ...;
}
```

The controller can get rather bloated at this part, especially if there is much customization to do with each table cell. I would much rather handle it in the cell implementation file.

One way I can think of is to declare a function in the header file of the custom cell, and then simply pass the object to the function in the table view controller...so it would look something like this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell setModelForCell:(MyModel *)model];
```

However, is this best practice? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this fairly often when a `cell` needs a lot of customisation. However I handle it a little differently. Example is this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CustomCellClass *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    ItemClass *item = self.someCollection[indexPath.section];
   cell.item = item;

    return cell;
}
```

Then in the header of the cell class I declare the property for `item` like so: `@property (strong, nonatomic) ItemClass *item;`

The in `item`'s setter method:

```
-(void)setItem:(ItemClass *)aItem
{
    _item = aItem;

  self.labelOne.text = _item.name; 
//And so on... 
}
```

This sets up the cell nicely and you can have different setter methods based on the type of object your model uses.

Hope this helps/

Comment: I know this is a little old but, when I try to add the setter method and I set the cell inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` my app crashes. It says the object is nil? I am able to set the title text inside the controller directly though.

Comment: That’s doesnt round right at all. Post a new question and perhaps link it or send me a message with the link and I’ll take s look.

Comment: Found the error, I was setting it with `self` instead of using `_`. I'm not too familiar with objective-c and just figured out there's a difference between the two now. Always thought they were the same